# Esri ArcGIS Server Maintenance

Tags: arcgis-server, license, pricing

I am looking at our quote from Esri and am not sure on the difference between two items on the quote. They are:

ArcGIS for Server Workgroup Standard One Core Additional Migrated Maintenance
Start Date:  04/19/2013
End  Date:  04/18/2014

ArcGIS for Server Workgroup Standard Up to Two Cores Migrated Maintenance
Start Date:  04/19/2013
End  Date:  04/18/2014

They look one in the same to me. They are quoting me for two of the first one and one of the latter one. Can anyone tell me what the difference is?

Comment: Yes the licensing is depend on the no. of cores and the more information please check the white paper http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/whitepapers/view/productid/66/metaid/1896

Comment: See page 3 of the [ESRI document](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/features/~/media/Files/Pdfs/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf) and then page 10 has more info.

Comment: Don't you think talking to your ESRI rep would be more appropriate?

Comment: rdctx how many cores does your server currently have? if 4 workgroup is ok - any more and then enterprise licensing is required.

Answer (score 1):

Some companies (like ESRI & Oracle) charge you based on the hardware that you are going to run the software in. One is the price for a machine with a single core (CPU). The other one is for 2 single core CPUs or 1 Dual Core CPU. To give you an idea, my Macbook Pro laptop is a quad-core (i.e four cores).

Comment: Yes you have license for 4 cores which is the max for workgroup. And probably required by your hardware.